# Can't restream RTSP with VLC

Tags: video, rtsp, vlc, ip-camera, live555

I have a linux server with VLC installed, and I'm trying to restream the IP camera (rstp). The command for restreaming should be ok, because from my PC, it runs perfectly. When I'm trying to run it from the server, there are some problems:

```
...
[0xb550646c] live555 demux debug: setup start: 0.000000 stop:0.000000
[0xb550646c] live555 demux error: Nothing to play for rtsp://.../live.sdp
[0xb550646c] main demux debug: no access_demux module matching "rtsp" could be loaded
...
```

The VLC versions on my PC and the server are the same. I've found that it might be missing live555 library, but that's not my case. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is re-stream than VLC is a bit heavy weight for that...

You need to check out the documentation http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch05.html

Or you can use this library on Linux with Mono...

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507218/Managed-Media-Aggregation-using-Rtsp-and-Rtp

It will re-stream any source for you and works with VLC etc.